# multiple argument from terminal using python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am able to run this properly using os.system. It is writing pcap file into text.

```
os.system("tshark -z 'proto,colinfo,tcp.srcport,tcp.srcport' -r filename.pcap > testfile")
```

But when I tried to give input file from termimal, I got following error:
tshark: -z invalid argument

```
host = raw_input("Enter file name: ")   
test = subprocess.Popen(["tshark","-z","'proto,colinfo,tcp.srcport,tcp.srcport'","-r",host,">","testfile"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]
```

Can anybody please figure out where I am making mistake?

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback you're receiving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emulate the `os.system` command, use the `shell=True` parameter to `subprocess.Popen` and provide the same command string (not an array of strings):

```
subprocess.Popen("tshark -z 'proto,colinfo,tcp.srcport,tcp.srcport' -r " 
                 + host + "> testfile", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

You need a shell to interpret your command line as you are using output redirection to a file ("> testfile").

In your example, you are passing each element of the string list to the execve() system call and hence as parameters to the `tshark` command (which gets `'proto,colinfo,tcp.srcport,tcp.srcport'` as the argument to the `-z` option instead of `proto,colinfo,tcp.srcport,tcp.srcport` and which won't know what to do with the `>` and `testfile` arguments).

As wnnmaw points out in his comment, using `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=True` with command lines built from user input (the `host` variable in your case) allows a user to pass arbitrary data to the shell. This can be used to execute (potentially nasty) commands on your system.

For instance, setting `host` in your example to `; /bin/rm -rf /` would delete every file on a UNIX system (assuming the user running the process had enough privilege).

It is therefore very important to validate an user input before adding it to the command string.

Comment: You should probably make note of the security risk associated with ```shell=True``` and un-sanitized input

Comment: Thanks for valuabe comment---